# Extra records when used as a sub query: Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, sql-limit

I'm a rookie developer with basic SQL experience and this problem has been 'doing my head in' for the last couple of days. I've gone to ask a question here a couple times and thought... not yet... keep trying.

I have a table:

- `ID`
- `Store`
- `Product_Type`
- `Delivery_Window`
- `Despatch_Time`
- `Despatch_Type`
- `Pallets`
- `Cartons`
- Many other columns (`start_week` and `day_num` are two of them)

My goal is to get a list of of store by `product_type` with the minimum `despatch_time` with all the other column information.

I've tested the base query.

```
SELECT Product_Type, Store, Min(Despatch_Time) as MinDes
FROM table
GROUP BY Store, Product_Type
```

Works well, I get 200 rows as expected.

Now I want those 200 rows to have the other related record information : `Delivery_Window`, `start_week`, etc

I've tried the following.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT Product_Type, Store, Min(Despatch_Time) as MinDes
FROM table
GROUP BY Store, Product_Type)
```

I've tried doing inner and right joins all returned more than 200 records, my original amount.

I inspected the additional records and it is where there is the same despatch time for a store and product type but for a different despatch type.

So I need a hand in creating a query where I limit it by the initial sub query but even if there is matching minimum despatch times it will still limit the count to one record by store and product type.

Current Query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS A INNER JOIN 
(Select Min(Despatch_Time) as MinDue, store, product_type
FROM table
WHERE day_num = [Forms]![FRM_SomeForm]![combo_del_day] AND start_week =[Forms]![FRM_SomeForm]![txt_date1]
GROUP BY store, product_type) AS B 
ON (A.product_type = B.product_type) AND (A.store = B.store) AND (A.Despatch_Time = B.MinDue);
```

Comment: Then why not add *Despatch_Type* to the `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` on that field too?

Comment: despatch_type has different values so when I group by it creates extra records so the sub query will return 220 records when just done alone not the 200 I'm after.

Comment: You will need to then *inspect the additional records* as there is probably yet another field requiring uniqueness.

Comment: I had the understanding that the reason that duplicate records where created was because of the duplicate in the column  I'm using in the group by, despatch_time. So if I can somehow limit that to one on the main query it will work out. Excuse me if I'm missunderstanding you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table as t
WHERE t.Dispatch_Time = (SELECT MIN(t2.Dispatch_Time)
                         FROM table as t2
                         WHERE t2.Store = t.Store AND t2.Product_Type = t.Product_Type);
```

The above will return duplicates.  In order to avoid duplicates, you need a key to provide uniqueness.  Let me assume you have a primary key `pk`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table as t
WHERE t.pk = (SELECT TOP (1) t2.pk
              FROM table as t2
              WHERE t2.Store = t.Store AND t2.Product_Type = t.Product_Type
              ORDER BY t2.Dispatch_Time, t2.pk
             );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I'm getting a syntax error. I assumed your bracket after product type was a mistake and I've added in two more where clauses so it matches the input in the form. Essentially filtering it by start week and day. Access highlights the section between my brackets from Select top to t2.pk if that helps.

Comment: @MasterSketchiggle . . . `pk` is whatever column has the primary key.  It might not be names `pk`.

Comment: Yeah I understand it's ID in the table.

Comment: If I run the sub query alone should it work excluding the where clause (replaced by the matching form input) should it work? As it does not. Excuse the lack of knowledge I've not used the TOP reserved word before.

Comment: I've just tried this exact query even without the where clauses to match input in the form and it has the same error. Any advice?

Comment: The issue was brackets. Thanks Gordon you legend you!